# Jmeter skips alternate row from CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am running API load test using JMeter. In which I am using a CSV file to pass the data.

API :

[image]

CSV :

[image]

CSV file :

[image]

Issue: JMeter always picks the rows which have isExternal = true and skips all the rows with isExternal as false.
This is something weird behaviour I am facing. Can anyone please explain the reason behind it?

Comment: Need more info, but check/show raw file with missing/extra new lines/comma/quote, also you didnt show the variables namea list in image

Comment: @rAJ were you able to find answer to your question? I see same issue in my case.

Comment: @Yogesh see my comments in the below answer

Comment: Thanks rAJ, I had a similar situation where I had two thread groups. Changing the CSV sharing mode helped me to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it doesn't:

[image]

Double check that:

1. [Delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) in the CSV file matches the one you set in the CSV Data Set Config
2. Location of the CSV Data Set Config (i.e. [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) might have impact)
3. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) doesn't have any suspicious entries, it would be also a good idea to [enable debug logging for the CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Previously I placed CSV file inside the API request but as I moved it under the thread group. It starts working. Actually, I have two APIs and I was passing the same CSV inside both the request. Now I removed the CSV from both the request and placed it under the thread group so that both APIs can access it. Thanks.